# Using namespace with nested dictionaries with two levels and two keys at second level

Tags: python, dictionary, namespaces

I have the following info structure:

```
items= {i1: {ref: i1_ref, attrs: {attr1: 'red', attr2: 'low'}}, i2: {ref: i2_def, attrs: {attr1: 'green', attr2: 'hight'}}}
```

`i1`, `i2`... are strings.

`i1_ref`, `i2_ref`... are strings also.

I would like have an object `i` to be able to retrieve the information as follows:

- `i.i1` to get the ref from *i1* (*i1_ref* value), `i.i2` to get the ref from *i2* (*i2_ref* value).
- `i.i1.attrs` to get the nested dictionary of attributes from i1,
- `i.i2.attrs` to get the nested dictionary of attributes from i2.

Code:

```
print(i.i1)
>>> i1_ref
print(i.i1.attrs)
>>> {attr1: 'red', attr2: 'low'}
```

Comment: what have you tried and what was the problem with it?

Comment: is `i1_ref` a string, too?

Comment: `i1_ref` is also string.

Comment: I used `SimpleNameSpace` and also `__dict__` but I am not able to get the results as described. I can get them separated but not using unique definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that adds attributes to a subclass of `str` to get the desired behavior.

```
items = {
    "i1": {"ref": "i1_ref", "attrs": {"attr1": 'red', "attr2": 'low'}},
    "i2": {"ref": "i2_def", "attrs": {"attr1": 'green', "attr2": 'hight'}}
}

# Subclass string, so we can add attributes to the instance.
class Item(str):
    def __new__(cls, d):
        s = super().__new__(cls, d["ref"])
        s.attrs = d["attrs"]
        return s

# Just a class that holds the dict keys as attributes
# and Item objects as their values.
class Items:
    def __init__(self, d):
        for it in d:
            setattr(self, it, Item(d[it]))

i = Items(items)
print(i.i1)
print(i.i1.attrs)
```

output:

```
i1_ref
{'attr1': 'red', 'attr2': 'low'}
```

Different solution with `SimpleNamespace`:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

items = {
    "i1": {"ref": "i1_ref", "attrs": {"attr1": 'red', "attr2": 'low'}},
    "i2": {"ref": "i2_def", "attrs": {"attr1": 'green', "attr2": 'hight'}}
}

class Item(SimpleNamespace):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ref

i = SimpleNamespace(**{k:Item(**v) for k,v in items.items()})

print(i.i1)
print(i.i1.attrs)
```

Although the printed output is exactly the same, the behavior is a bit different:
While `i.i1` from the first solution *really is a string* (with attached `attrs`), `i.i1` from the second solution is a `SimpleNamespace` object whose *string representation* is the `ref`.
This means `i.i1 == "i1_ref"` is `True` for the first solution, but for the second solution you need to write `str(i.i1) == "i1_ref"` or `i.i1.ref == "i1_ref"`.

Comment: Your solutions are great. I will take the first one because I can modify changing `str` by `tuple` at class Item so can use it also when `i1_ref` is a tuple instead a str.